# How to allow specific URL in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need a little bit help on WordPress URL.

In Wordpress Backend, I have One page and the page slug is: listing-detail

When I try below URL into the browser it's working as per my expectation.

**xyz.net/listing-detail/576905/**

But When I try below URL it's giving me 404 page.

**xyz.net/listing-detail/576905/abc**

I have to allow **xyz.net/listing-detail/576905/abc** URL to call same as **xyz.net/listing-detail/576905/**

How can I achieve this thing in WordPress?

Can anyone help to regard this issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You could add a redirect from **xyz.net/listing-detail/576905/abc** to **xyz.net/listing-detail/576905/**

Comment: @M.Doye I don't want to redirect I have to keep same URL xyz.net/listing-detail/576905/abc this is the client requirement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem.

Comment: Might be on topic over at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [WordPress Rewrite API](https://carlalexander.ca/wordpress-adventurous-rewrite-api/) to specify new endpoints and tell WordPress what to display for them.